# How to access models from the class constructor

Tags: javascript

I am just starting out with OO Javascript and I'm working to re-format some of my existing code to use OOJS however I have run into an issue that I'm hoping you brilliant people can help me with. In the following code I am trying to call the scroll function from inside the constructor of the Nav object, however when I run this code I get an error that "this.scroll is not a function". What can I change to allow the constructor to use the methods of the object?

**Code Updated @ 3:20pm PT based on comments and the answer below. I am still having the same issue "_self.scroll is not a function".**

```
function Nav(d){
    var _self = this;

    $('nav a').click(function(){
        var offset = -110;
        if(d.mobile()){ 
            offset = 0; 
        }
        _self.scroll($(this), offset);
    });

    return{
        //Define scroll method
        scroll : function(e, dist){
            $.scrollTo($("#" + e.data('href')), 1000, {offset: dist});
        }
    };
}

$(function(){
    //Create objects
    var device = new Device();
    var nav = new Nav(device);
});
```

**Update 2/18 @ 6:00PM PT**

I have updated my code to the following and it is working now. However I am curious what difference there is between using the object literal method I previously used and using the constructor method as I am now?

From what I can gather this works because I have defined the scroll method before it is being called; where as before I was calling it in the constructor before it has been created since it was being created in the return. However I'm not sure about the performance effects this change has and if using the literal constructor was better.

```
//Define Nav class
function Nav(d){
    var _self = this;

    //Define scroll method
    Nav.prototype.scroll = function(e, dist){
        $.scrollTo($("#" + e.data('href')), 1000, {offset: dist});
    };

    $('nav a').click(function(){
        var offset = -110;
        if(d.mobile()){ 
            offset = 0; 
        }
        _self.scroll($(this), offset);
    });
}
```

Comment: i´m confused by the mix of "this" "$this" and "$(this)"

Comment: I agree, better naming conventions would go a long way, perhaps change $this to anchor or elem as you are using it to refer to the anchor element.

Comment: I have updated the naming conventions above.

Comment: It works because _self = Nav which has function scroll. Previously you had _self = Nav but function scroll belonged to the new object you were returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue all along, is that this is an inappropriate scenario to be involving the prototype chain.

You should only care to add methods to the prototype when your object will be instanced many times.

**Just define a singleton:**

```
var nav = new function Nav(d){
  var nav=this;

  nav.scroll = function(e,dist){ 
    $.scrollTo($("#" + e.data('href')), 1000, {offset: dist});
  };

  $('nav').on('click','a',function(jqEvent){ // Event Delegation
    var $navLink = $(this);
    var offset = -110;
    if (d.mobile()) offset = 0; 
    nav.scroll( $navLink, offset );
  });
}(device);
```

Comment: This is a very optimal solution. Notice the upgrade to jQuery's event delegation.

Comment: What is the purpose for including (device) after the singleton?

Comment: @user3325478: oops, I meant to add it as a Nav constructor parameter as well.. edited :)

Comment: @user3325478: it is redundant -- in this case, it simply shorthand's "device" to "d" -- simply because that's how the asker's code was written.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `this` within the click handler you are actually referring to `$('nav a')` not the `Nav` object.

I'd set Nav as a variable using the following syntax and have the event listener refer to that variable.

```
var Nav = (function (d){
    return{
        //Define scroll method
        scroll : function(e, dist){
            $.scrollTo($("#" + e.data('href')), 1000, {offset: dist});
        }
    };
})(device);


$('nav a').click(function(){
    var offset = -110;
    if(d.mobile()){ 
        offset = 0; 
    }
    Nav.scroll($(this), offset);
});
```

Comment: I've updated my code using this suggestion, (updated above also) however I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Instead of returning a new object (that technically isn't even an `instanceof` Nav), you should create a property on the instance which calls the corresponding prototype property.

Comment: Changed my example to fit your syntax better. Also removed the event listener from the nav function which feels cleaner and prevents multiple event listeners from potentially being added.